# Play Framework - Update Tables with relationship OneToOne

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, one-to-one, ebean

I have two models with OneToOne relationship. When I insert, no problem but when I update the primary Model, it creates a new row in the second model.

My models.

Primary

```
public class Nodo extends Model {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="GP_ID")
    private GeoPunto geopunto;
```

Secondary

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GeoPuntos")
public class GeoPunto extends Model{

    @Id
    private int id;
```

My controller :

```
public static Result editarEmpresa(Integer id){
        if(!Secured.permiso()){
            return ok(e403.render());
        }

        Form<Empresa> submitForm = empresaForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (submitForm.hasErrors()) return badRequest(nueva_empresa.render(submitForm));
        Empresa _empresa = submitForm.get();
        _empresa.setId(id);

        _empresa.update(Integer.parseInt(id + ""));

        Form<Empresa> empresaForm = form(Empresa.class).fill(_empresa);
        return ok(empresa.render(_empresa, empresaForm));
    }
```

I hope you can help me.

**UPDATE**

I had to overwriter the method UPDATE

```
@Override
    public void update() {
        String queryString = "UPDATE GEOPUNTOS SET " +
                " latitud = :lat," +
                " longitud = :long" +
                " where  id = :id";
        SqlUpdate query = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(queryString).setParameter("lat", this.getGeopunto().getLatitud())
                .setParameter("long", this.getGeopunto().getLongitud()).setParameter("id", this.getGeopunto().getId());

        int rows = query.execute();

        queryString = "UPDATE NODOS SET " +
                " direccion_referencial = :dr," +
                " ruc = :ruc, " +
                " nombre = :nom " +
                " where id = :id";

        query = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(queryString).setParameter("dr",this.getDireccionReferencial())
                .setParameter("ruc",this.getRuc()).setParameter("nom",this.getNombre())
                .setParameter("id", this.getId());

        rows = query.execute();


    }
```

but I think that using an ORM I shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: Please, show the code where you update your first model (Nodo), in controller code I can see only Empersa.

Comment: But if it is. this cascade. Is not enought only with the primary model ?

Comment: No, I need to know how do you update your entity. For example:
`Nodo nodo = Nodo.find.where.eq("id", 1).findUnique();
nodo.smtn += 1;
nodo.save();`

Maybe the problem in code where you update the model, not in the model implementation.

Comment: I forgot to say that EMPRESA extends NODO, that's why I put the Empresa's controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem is because you getting your Empersa model with `submitForm.get()`. Maybe you need to debug your code or add logging to be sure, but my assumption is that your `_empersa.geopunto` after `submitForm.get()` don't have an id. You evaluate `.save()`, and ORM updates Empersa, then discover that geopunto don't have an id and make an insert.

If you want a page that somehow allow user to edit empersa, you need to pass ids of `empersa` and `geopunto` there, that if user submitting from that page this two ids passed into `editarEmpersa()` method. Here, you passing only id of `empersa`, you need the same logic for `geoPunto`.